# How are vectors linearly independent?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

So I have these $4$ vectors (they are column vectors, but I can't put them in the right form , somebody please help)

$v_1= (1,1,0,0)$

$v_2=(1,-1,0,0)$

$v_3=(0,2,0,0)$

$v_4=(0,2,1,0)$

The professor said that only $v_1,v_2,$ and $v_4$ are linearly independent.

He remarks by saying that that $v_3 = v_1 − v_2$; since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are clearly
independent and both have $0$ as their third coordinate while $v_4$ has a non-zero third coordinate, a set of three linearly independent vectors is clearly provided by $\{v_1, v_2, v_4\}$.

I did not understand this process. Can somebody please help me understand why only $3$ vectors out of $4$ are linearly independent? Thank you!

I know that vectors are L.I. if they have only the trivial solution , but I'm not sure how to apply this here.

Please explain as simply as you can too, if that is possible.

Comment: Please review, and include, the definition you've learned for linear independence of vectors.  $v_3$ is a linear combination of $v_1, v_2$, specifically, as your professor pointed out, $(0,2, 0,0) = (1,1,0,0) - (1, -1, 0, 0)$.

Comment: How are linear combinations and indepenence connected ? Im sorry i dont understand

Comment: A set of vectors is linearly independent if you cannot write one as a linear combination of the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Since you are a new user I shall try to explain. But is best if you show in this forum what you have done so that we can guide you.)

Linear Independence: $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n$ are linearly independent if the only solution to the equation $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_nv_n=0$ is $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=0$.

So here we have $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_nv_n=0 \implies a_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+a_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+a_3\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+a_4\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ which gives us four equations $$a_1+a_2=0\\a_1-a_2+2a_3+2a_4=0\\a_3=0.$$ Using $a_3=0,a_1=-a_2$ in the second equation gives you $a_3=a_4$. So we have got a non-zero solution $(-a_2,a_2,0,a_2)$ for $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_4v_4=0 $. Thus the four vectors $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ are liearly dependent.

You may try to show linear independence or dependence with any set of $3$ vectors from the above $4$ vectors to understand further.

Comment: But on the answers it states that only 3 out the 4 vectors are linearly independent?  How come here you say that all 4 are linearly dependent?

Comment: @GGGG: Here all four vectors taken together as a set are linearly dependent. But any three of them taken as a set can be linearly dependent. For this take any three from the four vectors you have mentioned and do the repeat the above procedure. If you end up with $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=0$ being the only solution, then those set of vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Im sorry , so i have to repeat this procedure ? I didn't understand. How can i choose the three vectors? Isn't there a simpler solution ?

Comment: You may try this. It might take time the first time but it is simple enough though. You will also intuitively find other ways to solve once you have understood this. Take $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ for the first try and follow the above procedure. Then take any other set of three vectors say $\{v_1,v_2,v_4\}$ and see what happens.

Comment: The problem is that i don't understand how only 3 out of 4 can be independent. ISn't there another way to do this?

Comment: Even a set with single vector is also linearly independent. Here the linearly independent vectors taken as a set are $\{v_1\},\{v_1,v_2\},\{v_1,v_4\},\{v_2,v_4\},\{v_1,v_2,v_4\}$. See if the above sets are linearly independent.

Comment: The other way is to check if any among the vectors $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ can be written as say $v_1=a_1v_2+a_2v_3+\cdots +a_{n-1}v_n$ with atleast one of $a_i$'s being non zero. (There is nothing special about the vector $v_1$ being written as the sum. What I wish to say is "Can any vector be written as linear combination of the remaining vector in the set. If yes then the set is linearly dependent otherwise it is linearly independent." I have take $v_1=$ sum for simplicity here.)